# Find all solutions $ x $in $Z$ to the simultaneous congruences for $x=1 (mod 2)$ and $x=2 (mod 3)$

Tags: congruences

In the first part of the question, it asks for 1 solution, so I just made $2k+1=3l+2 $  and found that $k$ is $2$ and $l$ is $1$, so $x=5$. 
But what does that mean to find "all" solutions for this?

Comment: It should be $3l + 2$. You can yourself verify that your answer 7 does not satisfy the second congruence.

Comment: Yeah you are right, my bad it should have been 3l+2 so x would l=1 and k=2 so x=5. I made a mistake

Comment: $k = 2$ and$ l= 1;x = 5$ is *one* answer.  But  l =3, k =5; x = 11 is another. and l=5, k = 8; x = 17 is a third.  Can you write a formula for all of them?  Hint it will be in the form $x = m \mod n$.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to conclude that the answer to the system of equations is $$x = 5 (mod 6)$$

There are more than one values which belong to the above mentioned congruence class. **All** those are solutions to your system of congruences.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $2|(x+1)$ and $3|(x+1)$.

So $x+1=6k$ ($k\in\Bbb{Z}$) and therefore
$$x=6k-1, \;\; k\in\Bbb{Z}.$$